# Is there an alternative for '<Button-1>' with bind() function in Tkinter ?- Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Drag and Click aren't the same thing so I was thinking maybe there is an alternative to `'<Button-1>'` for saying drag when the right click is pressed. Because in my project I can't display a menu (when I click on the widget) and press a click on a widget (to drag it) at the same time

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root,width=500,height=900)
frame.place(x=0,y=0)


label = Label(frame,text='˃LABEL',fg='green')
label.grid(column=0,row=0)


label2 = Label(frame,text='˃LABEL2',fg='green')
label3 = Label(frame,text='˃LABEL3',fg='green')

def change(event):
    
    label['text'] = '˅LABEL'
    label2.grid(column=0,row=1)
    label3.grid(column=0,row=2)
    if label['text'] == '˅LABEL':
        label.bind('<Button-1>', hide)

def hide(event):
    label['text'] = '˃LABEL'
    label2.grid_forget()
    label3.grid_forget()
    if label['text'] == '˃LABEL':
        label.bind('<Button-1>',change)
        
label.bind('<Button-1>',change)

def make_draggable(widget):
    widget.bind("<Button-1>", on_drag_start)
    widget.bind("<B1-Motion>", on_drag_motion)

def on_drag_start(event):
    widget = event.widget
    widget._drag_start_x = event.x
    widget._drag_start_y = event.y

def on_drag_motion(event):
    widget = event.widget
    x = widget.winfo_x() - widget._drag_start_x + event.x
    y = widget.winfo_y() - widget._drag_start_y + event.y
    widget.place(x=x, y=y)

make_draggable(label)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you should use "label.bind('<B1-Motion>', change)" , to drage while pressing

Comment: What do you mean ? Can you give an example ? It doesn't work I just placed the content of on_drag_start() in change() but It's very laggy I can't drag and click at the same time there's a bug

Comment: Anyone ? If there's another thing to make it happen at the same time

Comment: There's another solution ? Because I want to do 2 actions at the same time but they both require '<Button-1>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can bind a single button to perform two actions using Boolean values True and False. Look at the example below where I have used space bar key to change background color.

```
import tkinter


class ChangeColor(tkinter.Tk):
    change = False
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("300x200+0+0")
        self.bind("<space>", self.change_color)
        
        self.label_1 = tkinter.Label(self, text="Press space bar key to change my background color",background="Red", relief=tkinter.GROOVE, pady=20)
        self.label_1.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH)
        
    def change_color(self, *args):
        if self.change:
            self.change_to_red() 
        else:
            self.change_to_green()
           
            
    def change_to_red(self):
        self.change=False
        self.label_1.config(background="Red")
        self.label_1.config(text="My background is now red")
        
    def change_to_green(self):
        self.label_1.config(background="Green")
        self.change=True
        self.label_1.config(text="My background is now green")
        
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ChangeColor().mainloop()
```